# Pausing vbs code until shell script finishes

Tags: shell, vbscript, pause

I'm trying to create a script that will auto install a printer.
I found some code that I modified to give the user some prompts. I think the original was a batch file. There are 4 processes that have to shell out to run a cscript command. These are the ones that I need to have paused until they are done. I thought the WaitOnReturn option in the shell command would have made them wait but it doesn't I marked them in the code with 'Need to wait here...
Here is the code.

```
Dim fso
Dim Folder
Dim ProgramPath
Dim WshShell
Dim ProgramArgs
Dim WaitOnReturn
Dim intWindowStyle

'Dim objShell
'strInput = UserInput( "Enter some input:" )
strInput = MsgBox("This will install the default HP Print driver?",1,"Windows 7 Print Driver Install")
'WScript.Echo "You entered: " & strIpAddress
If strInput = 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please run again when you are ready"
Else '=1 Prompt for IP Address
    'WScript.Echo "You entered: " & strInput
    strIpCheck = MsgBox("Do you have the Printers IP Address?",1,"Choose options")
    If strIpCheck = 2 Then 'Does not have IP Address
        WScript.Echo "Please run again when have the IP Address"
    Else 'Start install routine
        strIpAddress = InputBox("Enter the IP Address", "IP Address")
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        'Create directories
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If NOT (fso.FolderExists("C:\DRIVERS")) Then
            fso.CreateFolder("C:\DRIVERS")
        End If
        If NOT (fso.FolderExists("C:\SCRIPTS")) Then
            fso.CreateFolder("C:\SCRIPTS")
        End If
        'Location of Windows 7 HP print drivers
        strSourceDriver = "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hpoa1so.inf_amd64_neutral_4f1a3f1015001339"
        'Location of Win7 built in printer scripts
        strSourceScripts = "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US"
        If (fso.FolderExists(strSourceDriver)) Then
            fso.copyFolder strSourceDriver, "C:\DRIVERS"
        End If
        If (fso.FolderExists(strSourceScripts)) Then
            fso.copyFolder strSourceScripts, "C:\SCRIPTS"
        End If
    'Delete existing printer named HP Printer   
    ProgramPath = "C:\SCRIPTS\prnmngr.vbs"
    ProgramArgs = "-d -p " & Chr(34) & "HP Printer" & Chr(34) & ""
    intWindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = true
    WshShell.Run "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs, intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn
'Need to wait here until the above shell process is done
    ProgramPath = "C:\SCRIPTS\Prnport.vbs"
    ProgramArgs = "-a -r " &  strIpAddress & "Port -h " & strIpAddress & " -o raw -n 9100"
    intWindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = true
    WshShell.Run "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs, intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn
'Need to wait here until the above shell process is done
    ProgramPath = "C:\SCRIPTS\Prndrvr.vbs"
    ProgramArgs = "-a -m " & Chr(34) & "HP Photosmart C8100" & Chr(34) & "-i C:\DRIVERS\hpoa1so.inf -h C:\DRIVERS"
    intWindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = true
    WshShell.Run "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs, intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn    
'Need to wait here until the above shell process is done    
    ProgramPath = "C:\SCRIPTS\Prnmngr.vbs"
    ProgramArgs = "-a -p " & Chr(34) & "HP Printer" & Chr(34) & "-m" & Chr(34) & "HP Photosmart C8100" & Chr(34) & "-r " &  strIpAddress
    intWindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = true
    WshShell.Run "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs, intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn    
'Need to wait here until the above shell process is done
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `WshShell.Run "cscript.exe " & …, intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn` should wait until the called shell process is done providing `WaitOnReturn = true`. However, output from the following simplified script (where assignments of `ProgramArgs` are *Copied*&*Pasted* from the original code) shows some missing spaces in supplied parameters:

```
strIpAddress = "10.10.10.10"

ProgramArgs = "-d -p " & Chr(34) & "HP Printer" & Chr(34) & ""
Wscript.Echo ProgramArgs
ProgramArgs = "-a -r " &  strIpAddress & "Port -h " & strIpAddress & " -o raw -n 9100"
Wscript.Echo ProgramArgs
ProgramArgs = "-a -m " & Chr(34) & "HP Photosmart C8100" & Chr(34) & "-i C:\DRIVERS\hpoa1so.inf -h C:\DRIVERS"
Wscript.Echo ProgramArgs
ProgramArgs = "-a -p " & Chr(34) & "HP Printer" & Chr(34) & "-m" & Chr(34) & "HP Photosmart C8100" & Chr(34) & "-r " &  strIpAddress
Wscript.Echo ProgramArgs
```

Output: `cscript D:\bat\SO\55303301.vbs`

> ```
> -d -p "HP Printer"
> -a -r 10.10.10.10Port -h 10.10.10.10 -o raw -n 9100
> -a -m "HP Photosmart C8100"-i C:\DRIVERS\hpoa1so.inf -h C:\DRIVERS
> -a -p "HP Printer"-m"HP Photosmart C8100"-r 10.10.10.10
> ```

Moreover, *the `Run` method returns an integer*. You could grab a process return code to a variable `RetCode` and then check if its value is zero (when all went OK) using

```
RetCode = WshShell.Run ( "cscript.exe " & _
        Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs _
  , intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn )
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay I was on vacation. Fixing the spaces and adding the RetCode solved the issue. I thank you.